# How to Match new Array with original array

Tags: php, html, arrays

It is hard to explain, but i will try my best.

In html, got a row of item A B C D E. They are not in array.

Now got another array which is `Num[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.

**Imagine** A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5, 0=6, 0=7, 0=8, 0=9.

Now, i use checkbox to check the item B,C,E and form an array `check[]={B,C,E}`.

Question is: How to know that the new array check[0]=2, check[1]=3, check[2]=5?

Sorry, i cant explain well, for me its complicated.(no code provided because its too long)

Comment: if its an even count on both arrays, just get the keys on the first one and use it on the second one, where are your codes though?

Comment: you may use array_search() on new array element with respect to old array you will get the position of new array element in old array.

Comment: @Ghost sorry its a full long code, i ady simplify, i cant copy the whole thing n post at here, its complicated because it contain few others function as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) which matches the two arrays up (the first one and the one with the values you want to find) gives you an array with just those items and the keys from the first array.  You can then use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) which extracts the items from the second array with the keys extracted in the first step.

```
$a1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
$a2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$a3 = ['A', 'D'];
$a4 = array_intersect_key($a2, array_intersect($a1, $a3));
print_r($a4);
```

which outputs...
Array

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
)
```

You can use `array_values()` if you want the keys to be sequential.

```
$a4 = array_values(array_intersect_key($a2, array_intersect($a1, $a3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `array_map`

```
$abc = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$num = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$newAbc = array('A', 'D');

$newNum = array_map(function($element) use($abc, $num) {
    return $num[array_search($element, $abc)];
}, $newAbc);

// Outputs: 1, 4
print_r($newNum);
```

The array_intersect solution is very clean too :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be a map, which maps the content `ABC` to `Num`.

```
$abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
$num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$map = [];
foreach ($abc as $index => $val) {
    $map[$val] = $num[$index];
}

$x = ['A', 'D'];
foreach ($x as $index => $val) {
    echo "x[$index] = {$map[$val]}\n";
}
```

If you have to do this only for one element, you could also skip the map creation part and use `array_search`;

```
echo $num[array_search('A', $abc)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$chars = ['A', 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E'];
$ints  = [ 1 ,  2 ,   3 ,   4 ,   5];

$given   = ['A', 'D'];
$require = [1, 4];
```

Combine and intersect:

```
$ints_chars = array_combine($ints, $chars);
var_export($ints_chars);

$result = array_keys(array_intersect($ints_chars, $given));
var_dump($result === $require);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'A',
  2 => 'B',
  3 => 'C',
  4 => 'D',
  5 => 'E',
)bool(true)
```

Use a map:

```
$result = [];
$chars_ints = array_combine($chars, $ints);
foreach($given as $char)
    $result[] = $chars_ints[$char];

var_dump($result === $require);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Use a map, but notice your number range is just a shifted index:

```
$result = [];
$chars_flip = array_flip($chars);
foreach($given as $char)
    $result[] = $chars_flip[$char] + 1;

var_dump($result === $require);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Finally by shifting and mutating the original array:

```
array_unshift($chars, null);
$result = array_keys(array_intersect($chars, $given));

var_dump($result === $require);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Notice that some of the map methods could fail if you have repeated elements in one or the other original array, as repeat indexes could lead to clobbering.